Mesh To Volume node rounding concave corners causes unwanted excess blocks
Maybe I'm looking for a workaround if it cannot be solved. Here's the original mesh I want to remesh with my Geo nodes setup. PS: I cannot use the Remesh modifier because it does not support complex shaders and textures. Shaders/textures will be gone after remesh modifier use.

But the mesh to volume node causes problems at concave corners, creating some rounding/beveling. Notice there is some volume rounding at the encircle red corner.

which is evident at the volume to mesh. Notice that all other convex corners look fine and consistent

and this is the end result with excess blocks created at the concave corner. And even a few removed missing blocks makes it worst.

This is my Geo Nodes setup. I tried messing around with the Density, Interior band width, resolution (size or amount), resolution (grid, amount, size), threshold, adaptive but I can't find a solution to this. Even with the voxel size is very low it still has the "rounding" effect at concave corner.


Expected result. Is this possible? How can I fix my problem. What am I doing wrong. Is there a workaround to this?? :(

I have an update it's weird because when I extrude opposite direction it no problem. Is this a bug in Mesh to Volume?


The problem is the Mesh to Volume node. Definitely inconsistencies in the way concave corners are handled. Looks like a bug or perhaps a limitation? I have logged a bug report for this please see https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/127129

Unfortunately this cannot be fixed. It is a limitation.
